# what is the first step on ubuntu 12.04 on laptop

Tags: 12.04

Am new on ubuntu and I would like to know what I would have to do first after installing ubuntu.

I had ubuntu before but I removed it because my laptop was getting so hot; but now I want to try it again. Any help is welcome. Thankyou.

**Specs:**

> Lenovo Y470, procesador: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @2.00GHz, 8gb Ram, 64 bits

Comment: Do you need help to install, to run properly (drivers), or for what else to do after **12.04.4 LTS** is installed? *I/We can help, but need that detail first.*

Comment: Please expatiate on your question. It's like trying to answer a question without a question